# Copied My Onsen Ui 2 App Folder to new pc, material font away

Tags: html, css, cordova, fonts, onsen-ui2

I am developing an App with Onsen Ui 2 and Cordova. Now I bought a new Pc and copied the by cordova created App folder(with Onsen UI 2) to my new Pc. Here I opened my index.html file on the computer and the font i 'normal' not material. How is this possible, how to change this back?

PS: I have not installed cordova yet on the new Pc

Picture of it: [Not Material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Prtn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you include the roboto font files, they are not packaged with onsenUI. Add this e.g. to your index.html:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300italic,300,400italic,500,700,700italic,500italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Or download the font somewhere on the web and include the css.
If the problem persists, run the application in your browser and use an inspector (e.g. Firebug) to see which file is not loading and check if this file is available on your filesystem or on the web.